# Selecting part of a row dynamically for colouring cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change the background color of cells, but not the entire row, based on the value of a cell.  I have some code that does what I want, but I'm sure there is a more efficient way and would like some help in making my code more efficient.  Listed below is a snippet of the code that performs the task.

```
Sub chg_bkgrnd_Color()

Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim counter As Long

Set rng = Range("k2:k23")
Range("k2").Select

For Each cell In rng

  Select Case cell.Value

    Case Is = "Closed"

      ActiveCell.Offset(counter, -10).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1 
      ActiveCell.Offset(counter, -10).Interior.TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
      ActiveCell.Offset(counter, -9).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
      ActiveCell.Offset(counter, -9).Interior.TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
      ActiveCell.Offset(counter, -8).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
      ActiveCell.Offset(counter, -8).Interior.TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
      ActiveCell.Offset(counter, -7).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
      ActiveCell.Offset(counter, -7).Interior.TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893


    End Select

    counter = counter + 1
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Why is [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) not being used?

Comment: I only need a range of cells highlighted not the entire row.

Comment: As Jeeped asked, you can conditionally format only a few cells you do not need to conditionally format the entire row or column.  That seems to be  a much easier way than tying to recreate what is already available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional Formatting would be best, but if you wish to use normal formatting, this is a streamlined version of your code:

```
Sub chg_bkgrnd_Color()
    Dim i&
    For i = 2 To 23
        If Cells(i, 11) = "Closed" Then
            With Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4)).Interior
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Following @Jeeped's suggestion, here is a version to use to automate this. In the worksheet's code module, place this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    RangeAutoBackFill "Closed", 11, 2, 23, 1, 4, xlThemeColorDark1, -0.249977111117893

End Sub
```

And then in a standard code module, place this:

```
Public Sub RangeAutoBackFill(Key$, KeyCol&, KeyRowLow&, KeyRowHigh&, FillColLow&, FillColHigh&, FillTheme&, FillTint#)
    Dim i&
    For i = KeyRowLow To KeyRowHigh
        If Cells(i, KeyCol) = Key Then
            With Range(Cells(i, FillColLow), Cells(i, FillColHigh)).Interior
                .ThemeColor = FillTheme
                .TintAndShade = FillTint
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Bonus points for addressing the actual question regardless of the method's applicability. I sometimes forget to address that.

Comment: Excel Hero,  I responded to Jeeped above and thanked him for his example.  I have some ideas on how I can use this going forward.  I was able to take your code suggestion and make it work for my example, as I explained above I did a poor job of asking my question.  Your sample provided a very good example of optimizing what I was attempting to do in my code.  I do have two additional questions since I am new to this;  What does the ampersand do after the "Dim I&" and can you recommend any Excel programming books that teach the Cells method in vba?  Thanks again for your help with this.

Comment: This could be fleshed out to a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event macro for a truly great answer in providing an automated responsive backfill.

Comment: @Aaron You cannot go wrong with any of John Walkenbach's books. like [this one](http://www.amazon.com/Excel-2013-Power-Programming-VBA/dp/1118490398/ref=zg_bs_4047_2). Also, there are many ways to reference cells and ranges from VBA. I published an article on my site many years ago that shows the relative speed of accessing ranges using most of the common methods. [It's an enlightening read](http://www.excelhero.com/blog/2010/06/when-working-in-vba-we.html).

Comment: @Aaron Regarding `Dim i&`... the ampersand is a shortcut method of declaring the variable as a Long. Many of the intrinsic variable types in VBA have a shortcut. These shortcuts are known as type declaration characters. Other important ones are `#` for Double and `$` for String. You'll hear some Yahoos bemoan them as bad practice. There is absolutely nothing wrong with their use. Sometimes I use them and sometimes I use the verbose (normal/contemporary) way. I started using type declaration characters when I learned BASIC on my Commodore PET computer in 1977!

Comment: @Jeeped I added your suggestion.

Comment: @Now you're just showing off.  First let me say thank you for pointing me to the John Walkenbach's books and your article identifying range methods.  With respect to the infamous Commodore,................. I don't remember the year, but I remember sitting down with the Commodore 64?????? one evening with at my HS girlfriends house trying to understand the thing out.  I had no idea what we were doing and no clue that one day I would make a living using computers.  Those were good times, thanks for the help, information, and the memory reference.

Answer (score 1):

You are inquiring about how to get the cells from columns A:D to have a highlight based upon whether the corresponding value in column K is "Closed" or not. [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) is a better solution as it provides an automated, background reaction to changes in column K instantly.

```
Sub Create_Conditional_Formatting_for_AD_based_on_K_Closed()
    Dim v As Long, vSTATEs As Variant, vCOLOURs As Variant

    vSTATEs = Array("Open", "Closed", "Pending")
    vCOLOURs = Array(3, 10, 5)

    With ActiveSheet.Columns("A:D")
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        For v = LBound(vSTATEs) To UBound(vSTATEs)
            With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
              Formula1:="=$K1=" & Chr(34) & vSTATEs(v) & Chr(34))
                With .Interior
                    .ColorIndex = vCOLOURs(v)
                End With
                .StopIfTrue = True
            End With
        Next v
    End With

End Sub
```

This routine may be well suited to a situation where you want to apply the CF rules to a large number of worksheets or as a recurring task on a regular import to a new worksheet but it probably is more work than simply creating the six rules manually.

I've simplified the selection of a backfill colour with the `.ColorIndex` property. You can find a table of ColorIndex numbers and colours [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/color-chart-with-palette-numbers/55accc04-5b03-490f-a9f1-56a926bed482).

Please note that I am deleting previous CF rules with an Applies to: of columns A:D before constructing new ones. That may be a consideration if you have other CF rules governing the behavior in columns A:D.

Using a formula in a CF rule and locking the column K reference with an absolute **$** indicator allows you to implement an Applies to: that is different from the column being evaluated. Use Home ► Conditional Formatting ► Manage Rules to view the outcome.

Manual method:

1. Select columns A:D with A1 as the [ActiveCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx)
2. Choose Home ► Conditional Formatting ► New Rule
3. Choose *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and supply the following in the *Format values where this formula is true:* text box:
    
   `=$K1="closed`
4. Click [format](/questions/tagged/format) and choose an appropriate highlight combination from the <kbd>Fill</kbd> tab.
5. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> to accept the formatting change and then <kbd>OK</kbd>  again to create the rule.
6. Go to step 2 and repeat as necessary. If you start with Home ► Conditional Formatting ► Manage Rules and choose <kbd>New</kbd> you can save a few clicks.

Your results should resemble the following.

[image: Conditional Formatting specific column based on another column]

Comment: Jeeped,  Thanks for your example.  I think I understand your point that it's more efficient to take advantage of existing Excel functionality rather than trying to create something from scratch.  That being said, I didn't do a good enough job in asking my question, so sorry for the confusion.  I wanted to know how to implement what I was doing in my code in a more efficient manner.  Basically, wanting to know how to dynamically update the background color of the cells in question without having to do all of the explicit instructions in my original sample

Comment: I have six conditions I'm testing for; Open, Closed, Pending, etc.  To do that with your example, would I simply add a select case statement after your   "With ActiveSheet.Columns("A:D")" and duplicate the rest of the code block for each of test conditions?  Thanks again for your example although I was able to incorporate "Excel Hero's" example which was more aligned with what I was attempting to do.

Comment: See the additional of a loop through two variant arrays above.

Comment: Jeeped,  That's pretty cool.  I don't understand all of the details, but I get how the code works at a high level.  Can you explain how the CF tool knows how to look at the code?  Is it just the :="=$K1=" reference?  Thanks again for spending the extra time and effort on this.

Comment: You have two variant arrays; one with the conditional word and one with the associated color change. The loop goes through each combination and assigns a formula constructed with the word (e.g. `=$K1="Open"`, `=$K1="Closed"`, `=$K1="Pending"`) and the color in each loop. When you create a CF rule based on a formula, you create it *as it applies to he cell in the top-left corner of the CF Applies to: range*.